# Is it ok to pass Integer.MAX_VALUE to elasticsearch without affecting performance?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to use Java API to query elasticsearch to get all distinct fields.

```
TermsAggregationBuilder aggregation =
        AggregationBuilders.terms("count").field(field).
                size(Integer.MAX_VALUE).
                order(BucketOrder.key(true));
```

I don't know the cardinality of field beforehand. Is it ok to pass Integer.MAX_VALUE without taking any hit on elastic search performance. Or is there any alternative?

Comment: I guess this might depend on many subtle details, many of them buried in your environment and configuration. Why don't you simply **try** what happens for you and measure before/after that change, and see compare numbers?

Comment: I tried on small size of data .i.e. 100,000 documents. So can't deduce performance from this data set. The number of documents on production could be as huge as 1B.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the elastic [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html):

> If you want to retrieve all terms or all combinations of terms in a nested terms aggregation you should use the Composite aggregation which allows to paginate over all possible terms rather than setting a size greater than the cardinality of the field in the terms aggregation. The terms aggregation is meant to return the top terms and does not allow pagination

And:

> The higher the requested size is, the more accurate the results will be, but also, the more expensive it will be to compute the final results (both due to bigger priority queues that are managed on a shard level and due to bigger data transfers between the nodes and the client).

So the answer is: it is probably *not* a good idea to use MAX_VALUE, not only due to potential performance impacts, but more because: it is conceptually wrong to do so.

Comment: What about two calls? One to get cardinality them using the value in next call. Is it better than using composite aggregation with scroll?

Comment: @ShashwatKumar I wish I could answer that, but I am not an elastic expert. If no better answers show up here, I would suggest you try to see if they have some sort of user forum where you could ask ...